# Is a __block variable assignment thread-safe to read immediately after the block?

Tags: ios, objective-c, synchronization, thread-safety, objective-c-blocks

```
__block NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse;

dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) 
        httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
    }

    dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
}];
[task resume];
dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
```

Is it safe to read `httpResponse` after this? The semaphore waits for the block to compete execution. If there was no error, will the assignment be seen immediately or do I have to synchronise or create a memory barrier outside the block?

Does waiting on the semaphore implicitly perform some synchronisation which makes the __block variable safe to read immediately. If this was done with `Thread.join()` in Java instead of a semaphore, it would be safe since it guarantees a happens-before relationship with the assignment in the "block".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems `dispatch_semaphore_wait` is also a memory barrier, so the value can be safely read.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes.

The semaphore lock essentially forces the thread that is currently operating to stop execution until it receives enough unlock signals to proceed.

The variable you have defined is modified on some other thread before the semaphore is allowed to continue executing, so your assignment should have safely occurred.

Comment: The order of execution doesn't guarantee memory visibility. The assignment can still be in a different CPU core's cache and not visible to the parent thread. That is why you need some kind of memory barrier. Just because you read the value after it's assigned, you will *not* see the latest value.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, this code will block on the executing thread (probably the main thread) until the semaphore lock is signalled. So - short answer, yes it should work, but it isn't best practice because it blocks the main thread.

Longer answer:

Yes, the semaphore will make sure the __block captured storage isn't accessed until it has been filled in. However, the calling thread will be blocked by the wait until the block has completed. This isn't ideal - normal UI tasks like making sure Activity Indicators spin won't happen.

Best practice would be to have the block signal the main object (potentially using a dispatch_async call to the main queue) once it has completed, and only accessing it after that. This is especially true given that if your session task fails (e.g. from network connectivity), then the calling thread will potentially block until the completion handler is called with a timeout error. This will appear to a user like the app has frozen, and they can't really do anything about it but kill the app.

For more information on working with blocks, see:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html

For best practice with Data Session tasks in particular:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/51127/nsurlsession-tutorial

Comment: This whole thing is already on a background thread, so I want to call the NSURLSession synchronously. Again, waiting for a thread != you can see the changes it made. Unless there's a memory barrier before you read the value, there is no guarantee you will see the assignment. Waiting isn't enough.